# is there a way for my discord bot to access the tenor website and then just add all gifs under a certain tag to it's output?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Title says it all. I have this discord bot that basically uploads cat gifs whenever a certain keyword or command is used. with my current code, I have to manually add the tenor/gif link to the output set so it can display that gif. Instead, I want the bot to just post any gifs of cats from tenor or any other gif website. I'm pretty sure those websites have a tag feature that assigns for example the tag "cat" to a cat gif. I want to know which gif is tagged cat and just add that gif to it's output set. Is there a way I can do this?

```
import discord
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()

cat_pictures = ["cats", "cat"]

cat_encouragements = [
  "https://tenor.com/view/dimden-cat-cute-cat-cute-potato-gif-20953746", "https://tenor.com/view/dimden-cute-cat-cute-cat-potato-gif-20953747", "https://tenor.com/view/cute-cat-cute-cat-dimden-gif-19689251", "https://tenor.com/view/dimden-cute-cat-cute-cat-potato-gif-21657791",
  "https://tenor.com/view/cats-kiss-gif-10385036",
  "https://tenor.com/view/cute-kitty-best-kitty-alex-cute-pp-kitty-omg-yay-cute-kitty-munchkin-kitten-gif-15917800",
  "https://tenor.com/view/cute-cat-oh-yeah-awesome-cats-amazing-gif-15805236",
  "https://tenor.com/view/cat-broken-cat-cat-drinking-cat-licking-cat-air-gif-20661740",
  "https://tenor.com/view/funny-animals-cute-chicken-cat-fight-dinner-time-gif-8953000"]
 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as catbot '.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return 

  if message.content.startswith ('!help'):
    await message.channel.send('''
    I only have two commands right now which are !cat which posts an image of a cat. !cats which gives you a video/gif
    ''')

  if any(word in message.content for word in cat_pictures):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(cat_encouragements))

  if any(word in message.content for word in cat_apology):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(cat_sad))
  
  if any(word in message.content for word in cat_dog):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(cat_dogs))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: where is your code? This question without code is totally useless.

Comment: if you want to get some link from other page then you have to `scrape` it - and it may need `requests` + `beautifulsoup` or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). But first you should check if page has `API` to get data without `scraping`.

Comment: @furas I've added my code. right now the input set of cat_pictures is everything that a person can say to get  the bot to psot pictures. the output set is cat_encouragements which is a list of tenor links. I want to make it so I don't have to manually add links to this output set.

Comment: Maybe start at https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#quickstart

Comment: as I  said before you may have to learn how to `'scrape'` pages with `requests` + `beautifulsoup` or `Selenium`. But first check if it has APi which you could use with `requests` - and @ChrisDoyle shows you direction. There is even Python example code using `requests`

Comment: I am using replit (the website). Do I need to download something to 'scrape' pages or can i do like imports and still use replit? Just to clarify I'm really new to coding so idk how exactly to use IDEs and whatnot. sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get data from other page then you have to learn how to `"scrape"`.

For some pages you may need to use `requests` (or `urllib`) to get HTML from server and `beautifulsoup` (or `lxml`) to search data in HTML. Often pages uses `JavaScript` to add elements so it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript (because `requests`, `urllib`, `beautifulsoup`, `lxml` can't run `JavaScript`)

But first you should check if page has `API` for developers to get data in simpler way - as JSON data - so you don't have to search in HTML.

As @ChrisDoyle noticed there is documentation for [tensor API](https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#quickstart-search).

This documentation shows even example in Python (using `requests`) which gets JSON data. Example may need only to show how to get urls from JSON because there are other informations - like image sizes, gifs, small gif, animated gifs, mp4, etc.

This is my version based on example from documentation

```
import requests

# set the apikey and limit
API_KEY = "LIVDSRZULELA"  # test value
search_term = "cat"

def get_urls(search, limit=8):
    payload = {
        'key': API_KEY,
        'limit': limit,
        'q': search,
    }
    # our test search
    
    # get the top 8 GIFs for the search term
    r = requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search", params=payload)
    
    results = []
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        data = r.json()
        #print('[DEBUG] data:', data)
    
        for item in data['results']:
            #print('[DEBUG] item:', item)
            for media in item['media']:
                #print('[DEBUG] media:', media)
                #for key, value in media.items():
                #    print(f'{key:10}:', value['url'])
                #print('----')

                if 'tinygif' in media:
                    results.append(media['tinygif']['url'])
    else:
        results = []
        
    return results 

# --- main --- 

cat_encouragements = get_urls('cat')

for url in cat_encouragements:
    print(url)
```

Which gives urls directly to `tiny gif` images

```
https://media.tenor.com/images/eff22afc2220e9df92a7aa2f53948f9f/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/e0f28542d811073f2b3d223e8ed119f3/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/75b3c8eca95d917c650cd574b91db7f7/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/80aa0a25bee9defa1d1d7ecaab75f3f4/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/042ef64f591bdbdf06edf17e841be4d9/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/1e9df4c22da92f1197b997758c1b3ec3/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/6562518088b121eab2d19917b65ee793/tenor.gif
https://media.tenor.com/images/eafc0f0bef6d6fd135908eaba24393ac/tenor.gif
```

If you uncomment some `print()` in code then you may see more information.

For example links from `media.items()` for single image

```
nanowebm  : https://media.tenor.com/videos/513b211140bedc05d5ab3d8bc3456c29/webm
tinywebm  : https://media.tenor.com/videos/7c1777a988eedb267a6b7d7ed6aaa858/webm
mp4       : https://media.tenor.com/videos/146935e698960bf723a1cd8031f6312f/mp4
loopedmp4 : https://media.tenor.com/videos/e8be91958367e8dc4e6a079298973362/mp4
nanomp4   : https://media.tenor.com/videos/4d46f8b4e95a536d2e25044a0a288968/mp4
tinymp4   : https://media.tenor.com/videos/390f512fd1900b47a7d2cc516dd3283b/mp4
tinygif   : https://media.tenor.com/images/eff22afc2220e9df92a7aa2f53948f9f/tenor.gif
mediumgif : https://media.tenor.com/images/c90bf112a9292c442df9310ba5e140fd/tenor.gif
nanogif   : https://media.tenor.com/images/6f6eb54b99e34a8128574bd860d70b2f/tenor.gif
gif       : https://media.tenor.com/images/8ab88b79885ab587f84cbdfbc3b87835/tenor.gif
webm      : https://media.tenor.com/videos/926d53c9889d7604da6745cd5989dc3c/webm
```

---

In code I use `API_KEY = "LIVDSRZULELA"` from documentation but you should register on page to get your unique `API_KEY`.

Usually `API_KEYs` from documentations may have restrictions or generate always the same data - they are created only for tests, not for use in real application.

Documentation show more methods to get and filter image - ie to get `trending images`.

Comment: thank you so much! your example code just straight up solved my issue. I'm trying to understand how it works and what it does, but otherwise, thank you so much!!